OperationFailure: Similarity index was not found (Cosmos DB for MongoDB)
I am working on a chatbot project, in which I am saving the dataset to the cosmosDB via MongoDB and using it in python to check the similarity of the user query embedding and the chunk embedding.
I am getting an error which is like: OperationFailure: Similarity index was not found for a vector similarity search query., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Similarity index was not found for a vector similarity search query.', 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue'}.
Here is the code I am using:
# simple function to assist with vector search
def vector_search(query, num_result=5):
    query_embedding = get_embedding(query)
    print(len(query_embedding))
    pipeline = [
        {
            '$search':{
                'cosmosSearch':{
                    'vector': query_embedding,
                    'path': '/text_embedding',
                    'k':num_result,
                },
                'returnStoredSource':True
            }
        },
        {'$project': {'similarityScore': {'$meta': 'searchScore'},
                      'document': '$$ROOT'}}
    ]
    results = collection.aggregate(pipeline)
    return list(results)

And
This is the code I am using for creating the new index: Which is like this:
# Here we are using the 1st method. 
db.command({
    'createIndexes': 'de_iceing_test',
    'indexes':[
    {
        'name': 'text_embedding',
        'key':{
            'contentVector':1,
        
        },
        'cosmosSearchOptions':{
            'kind': 'vector-ivf',
            'numLists':5,        # number of lists to use in the IVF index
            'similarity': 'COS', # cosine similarity metric
            'dimensions': 1536   # dimensional vector
        }
    }
    ]
})

Can you please help me to solve this error.
Please help me to remove this error as mentioned above and below here:
OperationFailure: Similarity index was not found for a vector similarity search query., full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Similarity index was not found for a vector similarity search query.', 'code': 2, 'codeName': 'BadValue'}


According to the official example provided by Microsoft, you need to set cosmosSearch as the index content,
{ 
    "createIndexes": "<collection_name>",
    "indexes": [
        {
            "name": "<index_name>",
            "key": {
                "<path_to_property>": "cosmosSearch"
            },
            "cosmosSearchOptions": { 
                "kind": "vector-hnsw", 
                "m": <integer_value>, 
                "efConstruction": <integer_value>, 
                "similarity": "<string_value>", 
                "dimensions": <integer_value> 
            } 
        } 
    ] 
}

So for your scenario, you can expect the index definition to be like below:
db.command({
    'createIndexes': 'de_iceing_test',
    'indexes':[
    {
        'name': 'text_embedding',
        'key':{
            'contentVector': "cosmosSearch", # here
        
        },
        'cosmosSearchOptions':{
            'kind': 'vector-ivf',
            'numLists':5,        # number of lists to use in the IVF index
            'similarity': 'COS', # cosine similarity metric
            'dimensions': 1536   # dimensional vector
        }
    }
    ]
})

